# Unable to connect to Redshift via Glue

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, amazon-vpc

Redshift cluster is in public subnet(public accessibility is already enabled ) and I am trying to add a connection in Glue . Security groups and IAM roles are already in place but I am facing the error "Could not find S3 Endpoint or NAT Gateway".

Do we need to have VPC endpoints / NAT gateway to access Redshift via Glue?
Btw I already tried creating S3 Endpoint and attached the route table, security groups to it but I got timeout error in this case

Comment: Can you share both security group configurations for the Redshift security group and Glue security group?

Comment: @AndrewNguonly For the redshift security group , ALL TCP traffic is allowed on all port ranges for the source 0.0.0.0/0 (this is just for test purpose) . And for Glue I created an IAM Role with Redshift full access and I attached the same VPC ,subnet,security group while creating connection in glue .  I did not get what do you mean by Glue security group

Comment: Does the security group configured for the Glue connection have a self-referencing rule and a rule for allowing all outbound traffic? Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/setup-vpc-for-glue-access.html